# Find the larger number from two inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a small program that just picks the larger number. My problem is that it want me to use an if else statement in the .js file. here is my html.

```
<body>

    BOX 1<input id = 'box1' name = '' value = '' class = ''><br>
    BOX 2<input id = 'box2' name = '' value = '' class = ''><br>
    BIGGER<input id = 'bigger' name = '' value = '' class = ''><br>
    <button id = 'go' class = ''>GO</button>
    <script src = 'js/javascript 03.js'></script>
</body>
```

I'm really struggling to write the .js file.

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {

    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;

    number1 = parseFloat(number1);

    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;

    number2 = parseFloat(number2);

    var bigger = 

        document.getElementById('bigger').value = total;


    if (number1 > number2) {

        bigger = number1;

    };

    else {

        bigger = number2;
    }
};
```

Comment: And where is code of js file?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: `number1 = parseFloat(number1)`? did you mean `number1 = parseFloat(box1)`?

Comment: yeah i guess that would be a problem

Comment: You could use `bigger = `[`Math.max(number1, number2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) instead of the if/else to find the bigger number.

Comment: working example at https://jsfiddle.net/b14apb7r/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/b14apb7r That example is a little too complicated for my program.

Comment: ` if (number1 > number2) { bigger = number1;}; ` remove the `;` and also as @EpicOrange said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest that you avoid spaces between properties and arguments. Although it seems to be working all the same, I've never seen HTML code like that.

This is what I came up with:

```
<html>
<body>
    BOX 1 <input id='box1' name='' value='' class=''><br>
    BOX 2 <input id='box2' name='' value='' class=''><br>
    BIGGER<input id='bigger' name='' value='' class=''><br>
    <button id='go' class=''> GO</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
            // Let's get the values and convert them to integers
            var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box1').value);
            var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box2').value);

            // Let's pick the bigger one and put it in another variable, "bigger"           
            if (val1 > val2)
                var bigger = val1;
            else
                var bigger = val2;

            // Let's write the value we just picked to the field whose id is "bigger"
            document.getElementById('bigger').value = bigger;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem! Happy coding :)